# Getting subscript out of range for an array of bytes

Tags: excel, vba

I am using excel vba to read a binary file, then get the bytes to an array of bytes. However getting subscript out of range exception, in the line 13

```
Sub GetBinaryData()
Dim aryBytes() As Byte
Dim bytInput As Byte
Dim intFileNumber
Dim intFilePos

intFileNumber = FreeFile

Open "Binary.bin" For Binary As #intFileNumber
intFilePos = 1
While Not EOF(intFileNumber)
Get #intFileNumber, intFilePos, bytInput
aryBytes(intFilePos) = bytInput
ReDim aryBytes(UBound(aryBytes) + 1)
intFilePos = intFilePos + 1
Wend
Close #intFileNumber

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails as on the 1st trip through the loop `aryBytes(intFilePos)` tries to access element 1 of `aryBytes` which does not exist (its declared dynamic & there is no preceeding `ReDim`)

Also EOF wont behave as you expect for binary access, try LOF instead

Here is a way to do it byte-by-byte;

```
Open "Binary.bin" For Binary Access Read As #intFileNumber
  '//only need to dimension once
  ReDim aryBytes(LOF(intFileNumber) - 1)
  '//easier to count from zero
  intFilePos = 0
  While intFilePos < LOF(intFileNumber) '//limit to Length-Of-File
    Get #intFileNumber, intFilePos + 1, bytInput
      aryBytes(intFilePos) = bytInput
      intFilePos = intFilePos + 1
    Wend
Close #intFileNumber
```

You can also do it in a single read;

```
Open "Binary.bin" For Binary Access Read As #intFileNumber
  ReDim aryBytes(LOF(intFileNumber) - 1)
  Get #intFileNumber, , aryBytes
Close #intFileNumber
```